# Why does converting a Joda DateTime to Calendar and back change the centuryOfEra field and nothing else?

Tags: java, jodatime

I was messing around with JodaTime today, and I expected this test to pass:

```
@Test
public void dateTimeShouldRoundTrip() {
  DateTime originalDateTime = new DateTime(2013, 7, 4, 0, 0);
  DateTime roundTrip = new DateTime(originalDateTime.toGregorianCalendar());
  assertThat(roundTrip, is(originalDateTime));
}
```

But it fails. I checked it under both JodaTime 2.1 and 2.2.

Further inspection (using the [SamePropertyValuesAs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/SamePropertyValuesAs.html) matcher) shows that the failure is caused by a difference in the `centuryOfEra` property:

```
originalDateTime.getCenturyOfEra(); // 20
roundTrip.getCenturyOfEra(); // 21
```

So why does *this* property change, when everything else - year, month, day, day of week, timezone, etc. - does not? Is this a bug? Shouldn't you be able to roundtrip a DateTime to a Calendar and back again?

Answer (score 1):

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) version 2.2 has an [isEqual](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html#line.120) method that compares only the milisecond, whereas equals compares the milisecond, chronology and timezone:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime();
new DateTime(d.toGregorianCalendar()).isEqual(d); // returns true
new DateTime(d.toGregorianCalendar()).equals(d); // returns false, as you observed
```

So either the chronology or timezone are not preserved by the conversion to or from a [GregorianCalender](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html). Leave a comment if you'd like me to investigate further.